# React header not updating after login

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

Hi so I have a `Login` button that I would like to change to `Logout` once the user is logged in:

```
{isLoggedIn() == false ? (
  <li class="nav-item">
    <Link class="nav-link" to="/login">{this.state.loginText}</Link>
  </li>
):
(
  <li class="nav-item">
    <Link class="nav-link" to="/logout">{this.state.logoutText}</Link>
  </li>
)
```

isLoggedIn:

```
static isLoggedIn() {
  return localStorage.getItem('token_id') !== null;
}
```

It works fine, but my issue is that it's not reactive and doesn't update when the user logs in, the user has to manually refresh the page/app to display the logout button. How can I make this update/change without reloading manually?

Comment: How are changing the view when the user logs in? you need to make this component aware of the login action

Answer (score 2):

You need to force the component to re render for it to recompute the isLoggedIn function.
You can do that with `this.setState()`, or `this.forceUpdate()` whenever the login state changes.

You should probably pass `isLoggedIn` as a prop if it is managed in a different component, or make it a state if it is toggled locally. You can set the original `isLoggedIn` in the `constructor` / `getInitialState`